# Feature difference between TinyX and DirectFB?

Tags: linux, user-interface, x11, directfb

I need to create a simple UI application but I'm confused which one of these two could be better feature wise. Can somebody suggest a  link where I can learn the difference between these two, or anything like that.

Comment: Read relevant wikipages on Wikipedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TinyX](http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/TinyX.1.html) is an [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) server. It understand most of [X protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System_core_protocol).

[DirectFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectFB) is not implementing X11 protocols. It is a library, and it is probably obsolete (not maintained very much by an active community, ...) or phased out.

Did you consider [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_%28display_server_protocol%29) ? It is supported by [GTK3](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-wayland.html) and by [Qt5](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/qt5.html) !

You still need a graphics library, e.g. [Qt](http://qt.io/) or [libsdl](http://libsdl.org/)

Comment: Thnak you for the information, I'm using GTK as graphics library. What do you suggest TinyX or DirectFB?